# Can't boot up a Kali Linux USB (UEFI)

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, grub, kali-linux, efi

I would like to create a USB with GRUB bootloader (or other) and Kali which can be used on any machine (alongside the main os already installed ). I've installed Kali on a USB (64 GB) stick and everything went just fine

Just a note: I've used another USB stick which had the ISO file on it during the installation . I've created two partitions like that:

- `/` partition: 57.5 GB
- `swap` : 3.5 GB as a swap area

In the end of the installation I've got a prompt that everything went fine, and the installation completed. The prompt said I should reboot my computer and start using Kali. but when I restarted my computer, I couldn't see any bootloader window, and I couldn't see my Kali in the  UEFI devices list at the bios as well. Why is that? And How can I boot up my Kali?

I've tried to install grub using a kali live session, [as described here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg65hm0dVO8).

But after entering this command:

`grub-install /dev/sdd` (`dev/sdd` is my USB stick )
I've got the message:

`grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.`

Which is kind of make sense because I dont have an EFI partition.I just want to be 100% sure before I do anything.

In order to be able to boot up my Kali-linux from GRUB bootloader? 
Should I create a `/boot/efi partition` or something like that during the installation?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi`

Since `grub-install` try to install in mbr

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I create a /boot partition? because as I mentioned, right now I dont have one. When I run the command you've mentioned I get `grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.`

Comment: You have to mount the boot partion created while installing. If you losed yor /boot you will have to recreate it from inside of chroot